# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP and currently, I am working on my PHP add client user account. I **cannot add to the database and I got this warning**.   *Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]:* Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens I cannot find an specific solution on my problem. Your help will be highly appreciated. Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';   

if ($_POST) {
    try {
$clientunum = "";
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$userpass = ($_POST['userpass']);
$user_fname = ($_POST['user_fname']);
$user_lname = ($_POST['user_lname']);
$user_bdate = ($_POST['user_bdate']);
$companyname = ($_POST['companyname']);
$user_mobilenum = ($_POST['user_mobilenum']);
$rbStatus = ($_POST['rbStatus']);

// ******* FOR PHOTO START *********
$file = $_FILES['user_photopath'];
$filetmp = $_FILES["user_photopath"]["tmp_name"]; 
$filename = $_FILES["user_photopath"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["user_photopath"]["type"];
$userphotopath = "usersimg/".$filename;

move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $userphotopath);
 // ***** FOR PHOTO END  ******
// ***** QUERY 
$query = "INSERT INTO client SET CLIENT_UNUM=?, USERNAME=?, USERPASS=?, 
USER_FNAME=?, USER_LNAME=?, USER_BDATE=?, USER_PHOTOPATH=?, COMPANY_NAME, 
STATUS=?, USER_MOBILENUM=?";

$stmt  = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt  -> bindParam(1,$clientunum);
$stmt  -> bindParam(2,$username);
$stmt  -> bindParam(3,$userpass);
$stmt  -> bindParam(4,$user_fname);
$stmt  -> bindParam(5,$user_lname);
$stmt  -> bindParam(6,$user_bdate);
$stmt  -> bindParam(7,$userphotopath);
$stmt  -> bindParam(8,$companyname);
$stmt  -> bindParam(9,$rbStatus);
$stmt  -> bindParam(10,$user_mobilenum);
$stmt  -> execute();

 //header("location:addnewuseraccount.php");
// echo "<a href='records.php'>View Records</a>";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "ERROR:".$e->getMessage();
} 
}

else{
header("location:index.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the parameter after `COMPANY_NAME,`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO client SET CLIENT_UNUM=?, USERNAME=?, USERPASS=?, 
USER_FNAME=?, USER_LNAME=?, USER_BDATE=?, USER_PHOTOPATH=?, COMPANY_NAME=?, 
STATUS=?, USER_MOBILENUM=?";
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed here `COMPANY_NAME =?,`